# MDL form invalid on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website, I can't post link because this is an admin/moderator protected directory, I am running Google MDL, and am having issues with a form.

As soon as the page loads, the bottom line of each input and text-area turn red, indicating the addition of class `is-invalid`, which is not there as I can see by using the developer tools. I do see `is-inavlid` as a tag on the `div`, but the code does not have that class added to the div, meaning the form invalidates itself on page load.

This issue appeared since adding `type=number` to an input.

> **INFO:** The code below is not the whole page, just the form, but the issue is still here (run snippet)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<!--BEGINNING OF MY CODE, ABOVE IS MDL LOAD-->
<div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="mdl-card__title">
    <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">Add a post</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">

    <form id="newPost" action="#" method="POST">
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" style="width:100%;">
        <input required class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="title" id="title-entry">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="title-entry">Title</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" style="width:100%;">
        <input required class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="media" id="media-entry">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="media-entry">Media URL</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield" style="width:100%;">
        <textarea required class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="3" name="content" id="content-entry"></textarea>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="content-entry">Content</label>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" style="width:100%;">
        <input required class="mdl-textfield__input" type="number" name="number" id="number-entry">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="number-entry">Post No.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield" style="width:100%;">
        <input required class="mdl-textfield__input" type="date" name="date" id="date-entry">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions" style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="#">
      <input value="submit" type="submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored"></input>
    </a>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a JS issue....that's what's applying the `is-invalid` class I presume.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that. Do you happen to know any solutions?

Comment: You'd have to dig into the docs as to what is considered invalid and when the class is applied. Obviously it shouldn't apply on load (although a blank is presumably invalid) but rather when the field loses focus.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it in the following way:

1. I override MaterialTextfield.checkValidity method
2. I add some custom class only for the first time of running checkValidity on the mdl field
3. If field is valid then class IS_INVALID is removed
4. If field is invalid and the length of the field is greater than 0 I add IS_INVALID class
5. If field is invalid and the length of the field is equal to 0 (required fields) I add IS_INVALID class only if it is not checkValidity for the first time for this field.

This is the code:

```
MaterialTextfield.prototype.checkValidity = function () {
    var CLASS_VALIDITY_INIT = "validity-init";        
    if (this.input_ && this.input_.validity && this.input_.validity.valid) {
        this.element_.classList.remove(this.CssClasses_.IS_INVALID);
    } else {

        if (this.input_ && this.input_.value.length > 0) {
            this.element_.classList.add(this.CssClasses_.IS_INVALID);
        }
        else if(this.input_ && this.input_.value.length === 0)
        {
            if(this.input_.classList.contains(CLASS_VALIDITY_INIT))
            {
                this.element_.classList.add(this.CssClasses_.IS_INVALID);
            }
        }


    }

    if(this.input_.length && !this.input_.classList.contains(CLASS_VALIDITY_INIT))
    {
        this.input_.classList.add(CLASS_VALIDITY_INIT);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also have an required attribute on the field, then the issue https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1502 describes this undesirable behavior, but sadly there is no fix yet.

It seems to be caused that mdl runs the validation while loading the page and as the input field is empty it will be marked as invalid. Obviously this should happen only after the user did start to edit the form.

One possible quick and dirty workaround is describes as:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('input[data-required=true]').attr('required', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This won't work if the fields are required. This is because a blank textfield *will* be invalid if the input is required. You may have to manually remove the is-invalid class manually, however this seems a bit hacky.

MDL has some methods that I have found to be pretty hidden away (also, I am  not sure if they existed when this question was posted)
The method is:

```
element.MaterierialTextField.checkValidity()
```

also check dirty can be very helpful if you have mdl labels overlapping text:

```
element.MaterierialTextField.checkDirty()
```

Here is a function I created using checkValidity

```
function mdlCleanUp(className){
  var mdlInputs = document.querySelectorAll(className);
  for (var i = 0, l = mdlInputs.length; i < l; i++) {
    mdlInputs[i].MaterialTextfield.checkValidity();
  }
}
```

then call after the page has loaded

```
mdlCleanUp("mdl-textfield")
```

You could also add your own class to the mdl div elements if you do not want to check validity on your whole document.